# Arch update failed because of signature unknown trust

Tags: arch-linux, upgrade, pacman

I was trying to update Arch and it failed and said:

```
error: onetbb: signature from "Torsten Keßler <tpkessler@archlinux.org>" is unknown trust
```

I looked for several solutions that didn't work already. I'm not sure how to fix something like this so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please be more specific as to what you've tried so that posters don't waste their time suggesting them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to reinstall the key using `sudo pacman -S archlinux-keyring` 
After reinstalling it you can try to refresh the key using `sudo pacman-key --refresh-keys`.

If above solutions don't work you can manually trust the key with the following command:

```
sudo pacman-key --lsign-key tpkessler@archlinux.org
```